# asp.net panels slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am not that good at jquery and java script stuff & i don't own this code. It's inherited from other developer who used to work in jquery and java script.

Below function has been used to create kind of slide show for asp.net panel for a specified duration.

```
 $(function() {
            var $div = $("div.display");
            $div.hide().eq(0).show();
            var totalPnls = $div.length;

            setInterval(SlidePanel, 3000);

            function SlidePanel() {
                $div.eq(($div.length++) % totalPnls )
                .slideUp("slow", function() {
                    $div.eq(($div.length) % totalPnls)
                        .slideDown("slow");
                });
            }
    });
```

Now every panel will be displayed for 3 seconds cause of  `setInterval(SlidePanel, 3000);`. What i need to change in this function that each panel displays for its own time? I mean panel 1 has duration of 5 seconds, panel 2 has duration of 10 seconds and so on..

Any help will be appreciated, thank you